# Making number ranges adapt to the smallest and largest numbers

Tags: php, logic

I have two numbers (for this example lets say 695 is the smallest and 36000 is the largest). Currently once I know the min and the max I divide the difference by ten and then cycle it through a loop to crate the ranges. It looks something like this:

```
$min = (int)$min-1;
$max = (int)$max;
$diff = ($max - $min) / 10;
$range = array();
for ( $i=1; $i<10; $i++){
  $range[] = array(
    "low"=>($i==1? $min: ($i*$diff) + $min),
    "high"=>($i+1)*$diff + $min
  );
}
```

This works great when the numbers are 695-36000. When the numbers get close together it becomes a little cumbersome to have 10 ranges. For example, the min is 34000 and the max is 36000 the ranges would be 34000-34200, 34200-34400, etc, etc.

Ideally if 695-36000 is 10 different ranges than 34000-36000 would be one range.

What would be an easy way to calculate how many ranges should show up and what those ranges should be?

Comment: I think that this purely depends on how large you want the range to be

Comment: I just want it to be "smart" I don't want it to be set to say 2000 because if I have 695 as the min and 100000 as the max the ranges should be 10000 or so

Comment: How do you *know* the max ranges should be 10000 with those two numbers?  It depends on how large you want the size of the ranges to be, and that has to be more or less a specific number.

Comment: Its all based on prices. So I could have something that is $695 and something that is $100000. So when I start to filter the products the prices get closer together. I don't know what the max range to be. current the range is whatever the difference between the min and max divide by 10. I'm not sure on how to make it smarter and for the range to be divided by 2 if the numbers are closer

Comment: How about a formula or some logic to determine what the size of the ranges should be? Could the formula be (max-min) / 10 unless that exceeds 2000? Is there some other formula to determine the size of the ranges based on the size of the possible prices?

Comment: that is good for the large ranges but still will not have smaller range intervals if the number is closer together. Basically I want to change the `10` in `$i<10` and make it dynamic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something to consider:

```
$diff = ($max - $min) / 10;
$range_max = 2000;
if($diff>$range_max) $range_size = $range_max;
else $range_size = $diff;
$creep = ($max-$min-$range_size)/9-$diff;

$range = array();
for($i=0; $i<10; $i++) {
  $range[] = array (
    'low'  => (int)(($diff+$creep)*$i+$min),
    'high' => (int)(($diff+$creep)*$i+$min+$range_size)
  );  
}
```